# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException : The operation has timed out

Tags: smtp, asp.net-mvc-5

I have developed an mvc 5 application from which I'm sending e-mail using smtp. Before sending email I have to export pdf reports in a folder and than attach those reports with email. When I'm sending single email than no problems occur but when I'm sending 2000 or above emails with attaching pdf reports than at a certain time exporting stopped and no email is sending from the application. When I tried to catch the exception I found following exception thrown :

System.Net.Mail.SmtpException : The operation has timed out

Can anyone please help me regarding this issue.

With Regards

Answer (score 0):

Sending a single mail will go very fast, but sending 2000 mails might take time, especially when sending files in each mail

set the timeout higher since there is much more data to process:

```
smtpClient.Timeout = 5000000;
```